# Using .htaccess with FastCGI

Tags: php, .htaccess, fastcgi, httpd.conf

I've readed that when using FastCGI to run PHP the .htaccess file included into the main directory of my site is ignored (right now i have the .htaccess file located in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs) My question is how can i apply the directives and flags currently on .htaccess to this domain only? can i have an httpd.conf only for this domain? where should i put the current .htaccess content to keep the same settings working?

many thanks in advance,

Comment: But i need to use FastCGI... no choice.

Comment: LOL, it's a bit long to explain here the reasons, but due to permissions matters, i need to use FastCGI and not Apache module. So i can use .htaccess in my folders with no problems, even using FastCGI?

Comment: Oh my god, What an amazingly constructive feedback! "You don't need FastCGI"... yes I do ... "Who told you that"... pff. If you can't respect other people's (well chosen) choices and are not willing to help out, please do not respond at all! Good to see that somebody else helped you FidoBoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apache will read .htaccess files as long as [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is enabled in httpd.conf. What you cannot do is put PHP directives inside .htaccess: this works only with PHP installed as an Apache module and would cause a `500 Server error` with PHP installed as either CGI or FastCGI.

Some configurations (with suphp and similar) allow for a per-directory `php.ini` with local settings. If this doesn't work with your setup you can change php.ini settings only with a series of `ini_set()` instructions (in an included file, most often)

Comment: Thanks djn, i have a php.ini per domain, but could i add htaccess directives into php.ini? RewriteCond, Options -Indexes, Options +FollowSymLinks... etc

Comment: Oops, sorry! i've read it wrong. What i can't use is PHP directives but i can use apache directives. Thanks for the info!!

Comment: I am having the same issue and have my settings set to "All" - what did you do to remedy this?

Comment: If you're using PHP > 5.3 you can use .users.ini file. It is the same thing php.ini but it is per directory (acts like .htaccess, but for PHP directives)
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php